# Transfering Conditional command from Raster Calculator of ArcGis to R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, arcgis, raster, r-raster

I would like to transfer the following code from Raster calculator of ArcGis to R.
`Con("diff_canopy" >= 1), "diff_canopy")`
This estimates a new raster which only contains the data from diff_canopy where diff_canopy is greater or equal than 1.

To solve this, I followed and adapted the code proposed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618060/conditional-command-from-raster-calculator-transfer-to-r):

`test <- raster (extent(canopy_sjd), nrows=nrow(canopy_sjd), ncols=ncol(canopy_sjd))
test[canopy_sjd[]>=1] <- canopy_sjd[canopy_sjd[] >=1]`

The code works fine, however, when I compare the raster obtained with R code with the raster obtained directly with ArcGis calculator, I obtained different values:

From ArcGis calculator: min 1.01598    **max 10.0271**
From adapted R code:    min 1.01598    **max 11.7207**

My questions are the following:
1) The adapted code match with the raster calculator statment?
2) If it matches, why the max values between output rasters differs?
3) If it do not matches, any other suggestions to fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

Always include some example data:

```
library(raster)
canopy <- raster(nrow=4, ncol=4, xmn=0, xmx=1, ymn=0, ymx=1, crs='+proj=utm +zone=1')
values(canopy) <- 1:ncell(canopy)
canopy <- canopy - 5
```

Here is a simple solution:

```
x <- reclassify(canopy, cbind(-Inf, 1, NA), right=FALSE)
```

An alternative:

```
y <- mask(canopy, canopy >=1, maskvalue=0)
```

One more:

```
z <- calc(canopy, function(i){ i[i<1] <- NA; i})
```

For small data sets, it is possible to use your solution (but not recommended). I would do it like this:

```
a <- raster(canopy)
i <- which(values(canopy) >= 1)    
a[i] <- canopy[i]
```

Comment: I tested your code with my dataset, and I continue to have the same problem. The max values between the raster generated by Raster Calcularof ArcGis and the raster obtained with your code, differs.

Comment: What you should do is use the example data that I created with Arc*. Then can we compare and help.